# query builder of Visual Studio 2008 with mySQL

Tags: visual-studio-2008, mysql

I am trying to filter my results in the query builder of Visual Studio 2008 so that when it executes the query to SELECT data from the field i chose, it will only retrieve last names that start with an user input. I figure this is to be done using the filter tab. SO i put a filter I used different filters but did not work with me.
I'm using mySQL database.

here is the code I used:

SELECT        Last_Name
FROM            contact_info
WHERE        (Last_Name LIKE 'prefixText%') will return null
........
SELECT        Last_Name
FROM            contact_info
WHERE        (Last_Name LIKE @prefixText%) will give me error
............
SELECT        Last_Name
FROM            contact_info
WHERE        (Last_Name LIKE '@prefixText%')will return null
................
SELECT        Last_Name
FROM            contact_info
WHERE        (Last_Name LIKE @prefixText)will return null
............................

here is the error I'm getting:
[URL=http://img180.imageshack.us/i/errorm.jpg/][IMG]http://img180.imageshack.us/img180/8983/errorm.jpg[/IMG][/URL]
please advice what is the correct syntax for mySQL to use in query builder of Visual Studio 2008 to return fields start with first letter that the user enter???

Comment: Is prefixText a variable?  Does "SELECT Last_Name FROM contact_info WHERE (Last_Name LIKE 'A%')" return anything?  Or Just this "SELECT Last_Name FROM contact_info Limit 10"?  Your syntaxt for the first query looks correct so I'm guessing there's something else going on here.

Comment: this (SELECT Last_Name FROM contact_info WHERE (Last_Name LIKE 'A%') ) will return nothing.

check this error
[URL=http://img180.imageshack.us/i/errorm.jpg/][IMG]http://img180.imageshack.us/img180/8983/errorm.jpg[/IMG][/URL]

I'm testing my query in query builder of Visual Studio 2008 and I tried many syntax no result like what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this code work OK for me.

SELECT        First_Name
FROM            contact_info
WHERE        (First_Name LIKE CONCAT(@prefixText, '%'))

Answer (score 1):

If @prefixText is a parameter then try..

```
SELECT Last_Name FROM contact_info WHERE Last_Name LIKE '%'+@prefixText+'%';
```

[LIKE Operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like)

Comment: I tried your way but I'm getting an error >>>

here is the error:
[URL=http://img341.imageshack.us/i/error2a.jpg/][IMG]http://img341.imageshack.us/img341/2333/error2a.jpg[/IMG][/URL]